# How to use SSS texture in Blender 2.8?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, shaders, subsurface-scattering

How do I properly connect the **SSS** texture in a Blender 2.8 using **nodes**?

**Blender 2.8**

Without and with the SSS texture:

[image]

Comment: I think your question is a bit too vague. You can plug it directly in the Surface socket of the Material Output, or mix it with other nodes like the Diffuse, in a Mix Shader...

Comment: i have black and white texture

Comment: oh ok, so what does it give if you plug your Image Texture into the grey Subsurface socket of the Principled BSDF?

Comment: before: https://ibb.co/b3npgYN
after: https://ibb.co/267hd9J

Comment: so maybe decrease its effect with a ColorRamp or a Math (Multiply) node?

Comment: Using "Multiply" works great! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: how do i mark your reply?

Comment: Hi. In future, please do not ask the same question twice. If you need to add more details to a question you should use the [edit] link below it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plug your *Image Texture* into the grey *Subsurface* socket of the *Principled BSDF*. To decrease its effect you can use a *ColorRamp* or a *Math (Multiply)* node between the *Image Texture* and the *Principled BSDF*.